# Is it possible to function chain send in Express?

Tags: javascript, express, chaining, method-chaining

I know it's possible to do something like `res.status(code).end()`, but can I chain it with `send('string')`?

Like this:

```
function serverError(error, res, code) {
  res.status(code).send(error).end();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you already have code to try your hypothesis with. Why don't you try it?

Comment: @Tomalak The development server I'm working on is only updated on merges to master, and I don't want to merge in broken code. There's no way to spin up an instance locally either. Do you know the answer?

Comment: *"There's no way to spin up an instance locally either."* That's awfully hard to believe. I mean... you can't install stuff and test your code on your own development machine? How do you even work? That doesn't make any sense at all.